# redux useEffect and useDispatch not working (max call stack)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new to redux hooks and react hooks and this is my code that doesn't stop rendering?

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const fetchUsers = async (page: number) => {
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_USERS_REQUEST,
      payload: { page }
    });
    try {
      const { data, ...result } = await api.fetchUsers(page);
      const user = new schema.Entity('data');
      const users = normalize(
        { users: data },
        {
          users: [user]
        }
      );
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
          ...result,
          users
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_USERS_FAILURE, payload: { error } });
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers(1);
  }, [fetchUsers]);
  const users = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.users);
  console.log('asd', users);
  return (
    <div className="vh-100 vw-100">
      <header>Users</header>asdasd
    </div>
  );
};
```

fetchUsers is an async method that i plan to use multiple times on loadMore and pagination, however, this is not working, how do i make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Your fetchUsers is changing on each rerender that is casing your useEffect with that fetch to trigger.

Try this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers(pageNumber);
  }, [pageNumber]);
```

Comment: also change the name of your page state variable to something else (or change it in fetchUsers). You shadowed that page variable.

const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

Comment: I recommend installing and setting ESLINT or TSLINT if you are using TypeScript. It can help with alot of stupid JavaScript errors.